# Hide Part icons when maximized, but show on minimized

Tags: icons, eclipse-rcp, e4, eclipse-neon

When creating Parts, I can specify an icon in the Application.e4xmi, which is used on the tab's title, as well as the minimized icon when the stack is minimized.  However if I remove the icon specified, it disappears from both areas.  How can I hide the icon when the Part is visible, but have an icon when showing the "peek icons" on minimize?

Comment: I don't think there is any straightforward way to do this. You would probably have to use a renderer factory to override the appropriate renderers.

Comment: Right, I couldn't find anything straight-forward, somehow in Indigo, it only shows an icon on the focused maximized Part, not also on the Parts behind the focused ones.

Comment: The internals of Eclipse 3 are completely different from Eclipse 4 (and I do mean **completely**).

Comment: Unfortunately, our migration requirements are not.

Comment: Images on the unselected tabs can be controlled - the CSS `swt-unselected-image-visible` property sets this.

Comment: OMG That's what I was looking for!! I will try it right now!